# BitArray and XOR

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for an operator based way of working with bit masks and bitwise boolean operations (XOR / NOR / OR / AND / NOT / EQV / etc).  Generally I *really* like an extension method style approach, but in this case, I find it a little messy.

Is there a terser way of working with bits in C#?

```
        BitArray a = new BitArray(0x001);
        BitArray b = new BitArray(0x100);
        BitArray c = new BitArray(0x010);

        BitArray test = a | b;   // won't compile
        BitArray test2 = a ^ c;  // won't compile

        BitArray test3 = a.Or(b);   // compiles
        BitArray test4 = a.Xor(c);  // compiles
```

Comment: Why not just operate on ints? int a = 0x001; int b = 0x100; int test = a | b; works just fine.

Comment: I don't think [the constructor that takes `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ty2t3fx.aspx) does what you think it does.

Comment: @RobertRouhani That works for this specific example, but what about an arbitrary number of bits? you'd have to have a separate struct for a 96 bit integer, for example.

Comment: @RobertRouhani: mostly because this fails.  int test3 = !(a);  Otherwise that's a good approach.  I need to have a full set of operators -- or at least be able to derrive those from primitive functions.

Comment: I posted it as a comment because I know it has limitations. And @sgtz, if I'm not mistaken the bitwise negation operator in C# is `~`, as in `int test3 = ~a;` (unless `!` and `~` act differently, my bitwise operators are a bit rusty.)

Comment: @RobertRouhani according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.100).aspx), ~ is the bitwise complement operator, and is predefined for int,uint,long and ulong. ! is logical negation operator and is predefined for bool only. ! returns a bool (true or false). ~ returns the complement e.g. ~0x01 = 0xFE

Comment: Given the fact that this fails, and that the constructor semantics are obviously quite unintuitive, this class seems very badly designed indeed. **Do not use**. Instead, write your own.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no way of doing it directly with `BitArray` - but you could always create a wrapper class which contained a `BitArray`, and define your own operators there.

Of course, if you're dealing with 64 bits or fewer, you could just use a `long` or `ulong` and be done with it...

Comment: Or if down to 32bits, just use `BitVector32` :)

Comment: @leppie If it's 32 bits, the easiest way would be to use a standard `int` or `uint`

Comment: @annonymously: Not if you dont know bitops. For a beginner, BitVector32 would be easier, especially when dealing with masks, etc.

Comment: @leppie: BitVector32 doesn't have the operators defined either, so you'd still need to wrap it...

Answer (score 11):

There is no way of doing this with `BitArray` and for a good reason: the operations like `Or` or `Xor` *modify the first operand*. That's not what `|` or `^` usually does.

If you wanted, you could create a wrapper that had the operators you want, including copying the value of the first operand before performing the operation.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, since there is no operator overloading in extension classes (the operator overload has to be defined in the class or struct itself), there is no real way of translating those methods into operators. I hope (as I'm sure many others do as well) that this will be changed in the future, but for now there's no way of doing that.